# How to use tornado as both a socket server and web server?

Tags: python, sockets, web, tornado

I know the httpserver module in tornado is implemented based on the tcpserver module, so I can  write a socket server based on tornado. But how can I write a server that is both a socket server and a web server?

For example, if I want to implement a chat app. A user can either login through a browser or a client program. The browser user can send msg to the client user through the back-end server. So the back-end server is a web and socket server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start multiple servers that share an IOLoop within the same process. Your HTTPServer could listen on one port, and the TCPServer could listen on another.

Comment: Thank you very much. Although I still don't know how the IOLoop works, but your idea does work magically.

Comment: The IOLoop knows about all the sockets in your process. It registers for events on those sockets (like when a client connects, or when a client sends data), and the loop executes related callbacks to handle those events. When you run an HTTPServer and a TCPServer in the same process, the IOLoop automatically handles events on both their listening sockets.

Comment: is there any way you can show some example code? I'm wanting to do as well and am just doing research before I attempt to convert my tornado web sockets into something that can accept connections from a client application (non-browser)